# ERROR: syntax error at or near "group"

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Hello I'm writing an sql query But i am getting a syntax error on the line with the GROUP BY. What can possibly be the problem, help if you can please.

```
UPDATE intersection_points i
  SET nbr_victimes = sum(tue+bl+bg)
    FROM accident_ma a ,intersection_points i 
    WHERE (ST_DWithin(i.st_intersection,a.geom_acc, 10000) group by st_intersection)) ;
```

Comment: Get rid of the parentheses surrounding your `where` clause and the `group by` statement.

Comment: #phylogenèse like this it can't compiled 'UPDATE intersection_points i
  SET nbr_victimes = sum(tue+bl+bg)
    FROM accident_ma a ,intersection_points i 
    WHERE ST_DWithin(i.st_intersection,a.geom_acc, 10000) group by st_intersection ;
'

Comment: Don't [cross-post questions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/186330/1872)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don' t understand your data structure. I create the following tables from your query. Please check table structure.

[image]

if table's structure is this

your query must be

```
UPDATE intersection_points SET nbr_victimes = (SELECT SUM(a.tue+a.bl+a.bg) FROM accident_ma a WHERE st_dwithin(st_intersection, a.geom_acc, 1000));
```

Answer (score 2):

`GROUP BY` is its own clause, it's not part of a `WHERE` clause.

This is what you have:

```
WHERE (
    ST_DWithin(i.st_intersection,a.geom_acc, 10000)
    group by st_intersection
)
```

This is what you need:

```
WHERE ST_DWithin(i.st_intersection,a.geom_acc, 10000)
group by st_intersection
```

---

**Edit:** In response to comments, it sounds like your `JOIN` is a bit more complex than the `UPDATE ... FROM` syntax would need.  Take a look at the "Notes" section [on this page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html):

> When a FROM clause is present, what essentially happens is that the target table is joined to the tables mentioned in the from_list, and each output row of the join represents an update operation for the target table. When using FROM you should ensure that the join produces at most one output row for each row to be modified. In other words, a target row shouldn't join to more than one row from the other table(s). If it does, then only one of the join rows will be used to update the target row, but which one will be used is not readily predictable.
>
> Because of this indeterminacy, referencing other tables only within sub-selects is safer, though often harder to read and slower than using a join.

*Normally* this would involve changing the syntax to something like:

```
UDPATE SomeTable
SET SomeColumn = 'Some Value'
WHERE AnotherColumn = 
  (SELECT AnotherColumn
   FROM AnotherTable
   -- etc.)
```

*However*, the use of `ST_DWithin()` in this query may complicate that quite a bit.  Without much deeper knowledge of the table structures, relationships, and overall intent of this update there probably isn't much more help I can give.  Essentially you're going to need to clarify for the database exactly what records need to be updated and how to update them, which may involve changing your query to this latter sub-select syntax in some way.

Comment: im trying with it it can't send the result the last error 'UPDATE intersection_points i
  SET nbr_victimes = sum(tue+bl+bg)
    FROM accident_ma a ,intersection_points i 
   WHERE ST_DWithin(i.st_intersection,a.geom_acc, 10000)
group by st_intersection;' it send this error also 'ERROR:  syntax error at or near "group"
LINE 5: group by st_intersection;'

Comment: i'am tring with this 'UPDATE intersection_points i
  SET nbr_victimes = (select sum(tue+bl+bg)
    FROM accident_ma a ,intersection_points i 
   WHERE ST_DWithin(i.st_intersection,a.geom_acc, 10000)
group by st_intersection)' it say 'ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
********** Error **********

ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
SQL state: 21000

'

Comment: @malyon: It sounds like the `JOIN` isn't as clean as the `FROM` syntax in `UPDATE` would need.  Take a look at the `Notes` section here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html

Comment: can you rectify your code please i don't understand

Comment: can you modified in my code please i can't find the result